What exactly are parashurama Kshetras ? Which areas come under it?
Is the region from Kanyakumari to Gokarnam considered as Parashurama Kshetras?

This question is similar to: The formation of Parashurama Kshetra. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ekAntika So from Gokarnam to Kanyakumari it is considered as Parashurama Kshetra?

if you read the purana reference, it appears that only north west part from gokarna upto sahyadri mountain is parashurama kshetra

I meant west to south (not north west)
